# How can I force full checksumming of UDP data?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

According to http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-netdev/2007/9/23/272755, Linux does not generate full checksums for packets destined for the loopback interface. I would like to force UDP checksumming. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to checksum a packet which is bound for the local machine?  Are you afraid it will get corrupted between RAM and... other RAM?

Comment: No ;). I am intercepting the packet on the local machine, doing some processing, then sending it out.

Answer (score 0):

The checksum is optional for UDP, you can also set it to 0.

If you need it for some reason, why don't you create the checksum yourself?  E.g.:

http://www.netfor2.com/udpsum.htm

Then (at least if you use raw sockets, I'm not sure you can do this with plain UDP sockets) just update the packet with your computed checksum.

Comment: I'd like to do the checksumming with plain UDP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more that your NIC has hardware checksumming support and Linux is using that and so never setting the checksum inside the kernel.  Try disabling hardware checksumming but beware of the performance overhead.